# What does “vehicle of death” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "vehicle of death" or "bridge to destruction" mean? Is it something tangible like coffin or hearse, or an expression more spiritual? The original sentence is as below:

> *Whether rational or not, it is a tough emotion to shed. As Harken so poignantly observed, "When we've created the vehicle of death, the bridge to destruction for our patient, that's another kind of pain."*

[as read in this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=IkuNBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=%22vehicle%20of%20death%22%20bridge%20to%20destruction&source=bl&ots=OgPJSSaTjE&sig=Qp5d9KxLuU2dXhsldQccrld3TIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5q8KQ2J7JAhXFW5QKHcVnBLwQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22vehicle%20of%20death%22%20bridge%20to%20destruction&f=false)

Comment: I think it means what they've done or created, when whatever that they did to the patient was the cause of death of the patient.

Answer (score 3):

*Vehicle of death* and *bridge to destruction* are not entities one ordinarily encounters in the ordinary physical world, and in context it is clear that they are metaphors signifying the cause of death.

> . . . when I am testing an unproven new drug or device and experience an adverse outcome, I replace the disease as the cause of the adverse outcome with myself, even though the disease itself may be fatal. The difference is guilt. Whether rational or not, it is a tough emotion to shed. As Harken so poignantly observed, "When we've created the vehicle of death, the bridge to destruction for our patient, that's another kind of pain." He had convinced himself that he would do great good, and now had to confront the reality that instead he had done great harm.

Answer (score 1):

A *vehicle* is a something that carries someone/something to a destination.

Usually this refers to a physical device or machine, such as a car.  *Vehicle* can also be used more abstractly where the "thing that carries" is a repeatable, defined method or process.

So, given the original example:

> ... "When we've created the vehicle of death, the bridge to destruction for our patient, that's another kind of pain."

Here, *vehicle of death* then means "thing that carries one to death."  Without additional context, a good guess might be the writer is making a comparison through a death he/she has caused, possibly via some medical method, versus one he/she has not caused such as death through the sickness the patient is experiencing.

Comment: Where's the answer? You may edit and make it more clear from OP's view.